# Loading multiple Stripe Checkout Buttons Very Slow

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a php page where I load stripe checkout buttons for 12 subscription options. The page takes up to 10 seconds to load. Is there a way to speed it up?. I can't demonstrate it as it requires the user to be logged in before the buttons will load.The code that loads the buttons is in a for loop and looks like this:

```
    <form action="https://www.example.com/plans/subscribe.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="customer" value="<? echo $stripeID ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="plan" value="<? echo $thisPlan['id'] ?>">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
    data-name="www.breakoutwatch.com"
    data-image="https://www.example.com/images/eyeLogo.png"
    data-description="<? echo $thisPlan['name'] ?>"
    data-amount="<? echo $thisPlan['amount'] ?>"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-panel-label="Subscribe Now"
    data-label="Subscribe"
    data-allow-remember-me="false">
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: You probably want to use the custom handler rather than loading the script 12x. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Answer (score 1):

It requires a little javascript work, but I'd recommend using Checkout's custom integration for a case like this!

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

You'd load checkout once, create your buttons, and add on click handlers. To identify the plan being chosen you could add a hidden `<input>` which is populated with the plan name based upon the button you click.

Example with multiple buttons

**form**

```
<form id="myForm" action="/charge" method="post">
    <input type="button" id="buySocks" value="Buy Socks for $10">
    <input type="button" id="buyShirts" value="Buy Shirts for $30">
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />
    <input type="hidden" id="product" name="product" />
</form>
```

**js**

```
// configure checkout    
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh',
    token: function(token) {
      // append your token id and email, submit your form
      $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
      $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
      $("#myForm").submit();
}});

// click on a button
$('#buySocks').on('click', function(e) {
   $("#product").val("socks");
   openCheckout("Buy socks for $10", 1000);
   e.preventDefault();
});

$('#buyShirts').on('click', function(e) {
   $("#product").val("shirts");
   openCheckout("Buy shirts for $30", 3000);
   e.preventDefault();
});

// open checkout 
function openCheckout(description, amount){
  handler.open({
    name: 'My Cool Shop',
    description: description,
    amount: amount
  });
}
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/ns2fezag/

Comment: Thank you for the full example and jsfiddle. I'll try that

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding this. (1) What's the purpose of the input hidden field? and (2) after accepting payment its not going to my subscribe.php page where I setup the subscription. That worked fine in my original implementation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While this answer isn't code, I ended up solving this by moving the Stripe checkout form over to a different page. Now my users click "Add to cart" and they're brought to a different page with a single button to invoke Stripe's checkout modal. It's not perfect but it's much faster and works.